# Tricky apply difference from two dataframes in a specific column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to compare the sum of an original df and rounded df.
If there is a delta from its sum, apply this delta, whether by subtraction or addition to the last quarter.

The first sum difference between AA is 4. (12-8 = 4)
The second sum difference with BB is 2. (14-12 = 2)

****Data****

original_df

```
id  q121 q221 q321 q421 sum
AA  1    0.5  0.5  6.1  8
BB  1    0.5  6.5  3.1  12
```

rounded_df

```
id  q121 q221 q321 q421 sum
AA  2    2    2    6    12
BB  2    2    6    4    14
```

**Desired**

```
We've subtracted 4 from 12 to obtain 8 for AA.
We've subtracted 2 from 14 to obtain 12 for BB
(when comparing original to rounded)    

Now the new final_df matches the sum of the original_df
```

final_df

```
id  q121 q221 q321 q421 sum delta
AA  2    2    2    2    8   4
BB  2    2    6    2    12  2
```

**Doing**

1. **Compare sum and create delta**

   ```
   final_df['delta'] = np.where(original_df['sum'] == 
   rounded_df['sum'], 0, original_df['sum'] - rounded_df['sum'])
   ```
2. **Apply delta to last quarter of the year**

I am still not sure how to complete thee second half of the problem. I am still researching, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: why is `0.5` and `1` rounded to `2`?

Comment: That is a result of a built in conditional. Those values do not matter, as we are moreso focused on the sum @Chinny84

Comment: @Lynn, posted an solution, does that answer your question?

Comment: @Lynn I understand now - but when I first looked at this problem I was thinking how we could go from the first df to what you desire - this appears inaccurate. Seems like you have an answer anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [sub](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html?highlight=sub#pandas.DataFrame.sub), [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html?highlight=sub#pandas.DataFrame.sub), [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html?highlight=sub#pandas.DataFrame.sub), [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)

```
# create the delta with difference b/w sum of the two DF
df2['delta']=df2['sum'].sub(df['sum'])

# subtract the delta from the last quarter, obtained
# using filter
# create a placeholder df3
df3=df2.filter(like='q' ).iloc[:,-1:].sub(df2.iloc[:,-1:].values)

# filter(like='q' ) : Filter columns that has 'q' in their name
# .iloc[:,-1:] : using iloc, choose the last column that has 'q' in their name, -1 gives us last column
# df2.[iloc][1][:,-1:].values : gives the values of the last column of the table
# the subtraction results in DF3, 



# update df2 based on df3
df2.update(df3)
df2

# updates will update the values of matching column from df3 into df2
```

```
    id  q121    q221    q321    q421    sum     delta
0   AA     2       2       2       2      12      4
1   BB     2       2       6       2      14      2
```

Comment: Hi @Naveed I think so - it looks like the final sum is the original sum values (which is ok too) - will check

Comment: Is there any documentation that explains how you did this? thanks @Naveed

Comment: @Lynn, i expanded explanation. hope it helps